# Which is first job or certificates

Tags: certification

Here goes a question I have in my mind after I finish my study and start looking for a job.

I have visited many recruiting websites and also clicked on many career tabs on companies websites.

There I have read many responsibilities and duties sections, which some the vacancies' duties seem new to me-where can I learn as fresh graduate about all those functions/terms used- but some of it-Oh man this guy is talking about me he is just reading my mind and knows my skills- makes me DROLL. But, suddenly I read MINIMUM EXPERIENCE 1/2/5 or maybe tens of years. and that is besides the question for certifications.

I do have studied CCNA and CCNA security but never apply for the certificates. My masters was CISSP curriculum, but no certificate too.

Now that after I saw these...

I wonder should I go for certifications and spend time and money to get certified while searching for a job??

Or should I just find any chance and then get certified along the way. Because I'm afraid if getting the certificate will not help without the working experience

I guess I'm not alone having the problem so I hope useful answers that can make this question beneficial for all

Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI, you're not qualified to take the CISSP exam. You must have a minimum of five years of direct full-time security work experience in two or more of the 10 domains. For all requirements, please review: https://www.isc2.org/cissp-professional-experience.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1) You had to actively look for the needs of the market already on your studies.

2) CCNA is not a valid diplom. If your diplom isn't "BSc" or "MSc", it won't be enough.

3) You had to create at least a minimal work experience during your studies. It can be for example "practicant job", or any similar.

4) If you didn't, you had to look for the worst jobs, for the worst wage - *which you can later "sell" as reference!*

5) Try to "sell" your (longer) homework projects on the uni as work projects. Don't lie, only expain them as if they had been work projects in the uni. It will be better as the nothing as you currently have.

6) Applying a job have only a small chance of accept in your case, maybe you will need to apply even for 50, 100 times until you get a positive answer. *Don't stop!*

Comment: Thanks.. the CCNA thing I had it during my BSc degree course. it was part of the curriculum.Then comes my master structured as the CISSP curriculum.I got my internship-one semester- that can be counted as the working experience I had until now.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the companies require certification in a particular field for them to even consider you as a viable candidate for the job in question. Most employers would openly state this in their requirements.

Speaking from my personal experience, I applied for a job which did NOT state a Linux certification as their requirement for the job but "preferred" such candidates over others. I do NOT have much experience. In fact, all of the other candidates where fresh out of university too.

I believe you can in fact get an edge over your peers by getting certified in your particular area of expertise, especially when you have no experience.